# file upload issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, upload

I will need client (end user) through browser to upload big files (e.g. similar to Youtube's scenario which uploads big video files), the file size should be no larger than 500M bytes.

I am using ASP.Net + C# + VSTS + IIS 7.0 as my development platform. Any ideas or good practices about how to handle big file upload issue? Any reference samples or documents are appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

```
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="300" maxRequestLength="512000" />
    </system.web>
```

This will not work in IIS7! httpRuntime is for IIS6 and bellow. The correct way to allow large file uploads in IIS7 is:

1) Add the following lines to the web.config file:

[Web.config] maxAllowedContentLength attribute for IIS7

```
<system.webServer>
   <security >
      <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1024000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```

2)Then open the file C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config and find the line:

```
<section name="requestFiltering" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

overrideModeDefault should be Allow.

Comment: One question about the meaning of "executionTimeout" parameter in IIS 6. Does it mean max time of the whole time of upload process? Or it means max idle time (idle I mean no file chunk is transferred from browser to server, so if continue to transfer file chunks, even if slow, there will no time out)?

Comment: Another question is, is there a parameter to specify timeout in IIS 7?

Comment: I am almost sure that exectutionTimeout applies to IIS7 as well. In concern with your first question: the timeout specifies the maximum number of seconds that a request is allowed to execute before being automatically shut down by ASP.NET. i.e. if your upload is not completed in 110 seconds (by default) ASP will shut down the process.

Answer (score 2):

The answers to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285120/upload-large-files-in-net) recommend [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/) or 
[NeatUpload](http://www.brettle.com/neatupload) for uploading large files through the browser.  NeatUpload is an ASP.NET componant which might well fit with your environment.

There is also [JUpload](http://jupload.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks Colin, one more question, why using RIA based solution is preferred, because better upload performance or something else?

Comment: Browser support for standard HTTP doesn't allow things like specifying which file types are allowed, also stuff like progressbars are better supported by flash/java

Comment: 1. Using FileUpload control can not specify file type? I am confused. 2. I think using non-RIA based solution could also implement progress bar, like how we upload attachment is Gmail. So, it does not mean using plain Http can not implement progress bar. Any comments?

Comment: One question about the meaning of "executionTimeout" parameter in IIS 6. Does it mean max time of the whole time of upload process? Or it means max idle time (idle I mean no file chunk is transferred from browser to server, so if continue to transfer file chunks, even if slow, there will no time out)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set **maxRequestLength** to appropriately handle big file and also set **executionTimeout** so that IIS does not abandon the request, in web.config file

```
<system.web>
     <httpRuntime executionTimeout="300" maxRequestLength="512000" />
</system.web>
```

Much more detailes are [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx) in Jon Gallowy's article about uploading big files.

Here is article on [MSDN](http://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=5&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Faa479405.aspx&ei=76E8SqjRMJCTkAXVzZmmDg&usg=AFQjCNFHf9AiItNsVdbVwKlC5Lh7UWflUQ&sig2=blTvkdSDiTkUBU5VSoU7dg) about uploading files in asp.net 2.0

Comment: Thanks TheVillageIdiot, one more question, why using RIA based solution is preferred, because better upload performance or something else?

Comment: I think with RIA you can give better feedback for the long running operation to user.

Comment: Thanks, 1. so only user experience benefits? No upload performance or other benefits consideratinos? 2. Why using non-RIA based solution could not have good user experience, could you give me an example please?

Comment: One question about the meaning of "executionTimeout" parameter. Does it mean max time of the whole time of upload process? Or it means max idle time (idle I mean no file chunk is transferred from browser to server, so if continue to transfer file chunks, even if slow, there will no time out)?

Comment: From one IBM document [http://is.gd/17ZXG]:- The executionTimeout parameter specifies the maximum number of seconds that a request, such as opening a Websheet, is allowed to execute before being automatically shut down by Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS).

Comment: here is a page for IIS 7 configuration parameters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347568(VS.85).aspx

Comment: 1. Looks like no timeout setting for IIS 7.0? 2. For the definition of timeout, I still have a confusion. Suppose I set timeout value to 5 minutes, and I upload a file, which is 10M and upload at rate of 1M/minute, which continues to send upload request to server but takes more than 5 minutes (10 minutes), in this scenario, does it mean timeout or not?

Answer (score 1):

Nearly all sites that handle very large uploads do so by default using Adobe Flash. Usually they'll fall back to a simple browser upload, but managing things the progress of the current upload is significantly easier to do in flash.

Comment: I am confused, you suggest we use flash or not?

Comment: I think the recommendation is use flash (or java), but allow standard HTTP upload if the user doesn't have flash/java available

Comment: why using flash (or java) based solution is preferred, because better upload performance or something else?

Comment: One question about the meaning of "executionTimeout" parameter in IIS 6. Does it mean max time of the whole time of upload process? Or it means max idle time (idle I mean no file chunk is transferred from browser to server, so if continue to transfer file chunks, even if slow, there will no time out)?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and found the solution based on [Jonathan's code here](https://forums.asp.net/t/1742612.aspx?How+to+upload+a+big+file+in+Mvc+). There are some problem with his code, but here is my solution. If you want to upload a large file, something like 1Gbyte file, you have to chuck the file and send it through several request (one request gives time out). first you set the max limit for client and server side.

```
<system.webServer>
 <security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
  </requestFiltering>
 </security>
<system.webServer>
```

and

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
</system.web>
```

then chunk the file, and send each chuck, wait for response and send the next chunk. here is the javascript and controller code.

```
    <div id="VideoDiv">
        <label>Filename:</label>
        <input type="file" id="fileInput" /><br/><br/>
        <input type="button" id="btnUpload" value="Upload a presentation"/><br/><br/>
        <div id="progressbar_container" style="width: 100%; height: 30px; position: relative; background-color: grey; display: none">
            <div id="progressbar" style="width: 0%; height: 100%; position: absolute; background-color: green"></div>
            <span id="progressbar_label" style="position: absolute; left: 35%; top: 20%">Uploading...</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript code to chuck, call controller and update progressbar:

```
        var progressBarStart = function() {
            $("#progressbar_container").show();
        }

        var progressBarUpdate = function (percentage) {
            $('#progressbar_label').html(percentage + "%");
            $("#progressbar").width(percentage + "%");
        }

        var progressBarComplete = function() {
            $("#progressbar_container").fadeOut(500);
        }

        var file;

        $('#fileInput').change(function(e) {
            file = e.target.files[0];
        });

        var uploadCompleted = function() {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('fileName', file.name);
            formData.append('completed', true);

            var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr2.onload = function() {
                progressBarUpdate(100);
                progressBarComplete();
            }
            xhr2.open("POST", "/Upload/UploadComplete?fileName=" + file.name + "&complete=" + 1, true);
            xhr2.send(formData);
        }

        var multiUpload = function(count, counter, blob, completed, start, end, bytesPerChunk) {
            counter = counter + 1;
            if (counter <= count) {
                var chunk = blob.slice(start, end);
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onload = function() {
                    start = end;
                    end = start + bytesPerChunk;
                    if (count == counter) {
                        uploadCompleted();
                    } else {
                        var percentage = (counter / count) * 100;
                        progressBarUpdate(percentage);
                        multiUpload(count, counter, blob, completed, start, end, bytesPerChunk);
                    }
                }
                xhr.open("POST", "/Upload/MultiUpload?id=" + counter.toString() + "&fileName=" + file.name, true);
                xhr.send(chunk);
            }
        }

        $("#VideoDiv").on("click", "#btnUpload", function() {
            var blob = file;
            var bytesPerChunk = 3757000;
            var size = blob.size;

            var start = 0;
            var end = bytesPerChunk;
            var completed = 0;
            var count = size % bytesPerChunk == 0 ? size / bytesPerChunk : Math.floor(size / bytesPerChunk) + 1;
            var counter = 0;
            progressBarStart();
            multiUpload(count, counter, blob, completed, start, end, bytesPerChunk);
        });
```

and here is the upload controller to store the chucnk in ("App_Data/Videos/Temp") and later merge them and store in ("App_Data/Videos"):

```
public class UploadController : Controller
{
    private string videoAddress = "~/App_Data/Videos";

    [HttpPost]
    public string MultiUpload(string id, string fileName)
    {
        var chunkNumber = id;
        var chunks = Request.InputStream;
        string path = Server.MapPath(videoAddress+"/Temp");
        string newpath = Path.Combine(path, fileName+chunkNumber);
        using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(newpath))
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[3757000];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead=Request.InputStream.Read(bytes,0,bytes.Length))>0)
            {
                fs.Write(bytes,0,bytesRead);
            }
        }
        return "done";
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string UploadComplete(string fileName, string complete)
    {
        string tempPath = Server.MapPath(videoAddress + "/Temp");
        string videoPath = Server.MapPath(videoAddress);
        string newPath = Path.Combine(tempPath, fileName);
        if (complete=="1")
        {
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(tempPath).Where(p=>p.Contains(fileName)).OrderBy(p => Int32.Parse(p.Replace(fileName, "$").Split('$')[1])).ToArray();
            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                MergeFiles(newPath, filePath);
            }
        }
        System.IO.File.Move(Path.Combine(tempPath, fileName),Path.Combine(videoPath,fileName));
        return "success";
    }

    private static void MergeFiles(string file1, string file2)
    {
        FileStream fs1 = null;
        FileStream fs2 = null;
        try
        {
            fs1 = System.IO.File.Open(file1, FileMode.Append);
            fs2 = System.IO.File.Open(file2, FileMode.Open);
            byte[] fs2Content = new byte[fs2.Length];
            fs2.Read(fs2Content, 0, (int) fs2.Length);
            fs1.Write(fs2Content, 0, (int) fs2.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + " : " + ex.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (fs1 != null) fs1.Close();
            if (fs2 != null) fs2.Close();
            System.IO.File.Delete(file2);
        }
    }
}
```

However, if two users at same time upload files with same name, there will be some problem, and you have to handle this issue. By reading responseText, you can catch some error and exception and trim it.