# PHP upload file with resume functionality

Tags: java, php, flash, http, file-upload

Hi I have a question, I want to do an upload script that can take rather big files 500MB, 1GB
and upload it with resume functionality. Is this possible with just PHP or is there other solution like Java Applet, Flash and which one would be best for this case?

Comment: Does it have to be in the browser, or is using specialized client software an option as well?

Comment: It should be web/browser application

Comment: Look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285120/upload-large-files-in-net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP is a server-side language so you really can't subsitute it with a Java Applet or Flash. Those are client-side technologies executed inside the browser. For uploading you need both a client and a server.

**Resuming a HTTP upload is not possible**, no matter the HTTP application platform, whether it's J2EE, Python, Rails or ASP.NET. It's just the restriction of the HTTP protocol.

One way to accomplish the resume functionality is by having the files uploaded into a standards-compliant FTP server, using a proper browser component. In that case you'd need a custom input solution, perhaps a Java Applet such as [jClientUpload](http://www.javazoom.net/applets/jclientupload/documentation/installation.html). Files in size of several hundred megabytes are too much for Flash.