# What are the ways to send files from client's browser to server in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I'm looking for possible ways for sending files from browser to server.
One obvious way is using form with enctype='multipart/form-data'.
I wonder if there are other ways than this.

The reason I ask you this question is this file uploader: http://aspnetajax.componentart.com/control-specific/upload/features/core_features/WebForm1.aspx

It's not flash based, but it sends the file in a way that it gives you a progress bar, but when you send a file with form with enctype='multipart/form-data' the whole file will be send to the server so you can't actually show a progress bar of uploading process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually get a progress bar for a regular file upload, but as the server only will handle one request at a time for each user, you have to use session-less requests to ask the server for the upload progress.

So, on the server you need to set up a way to identify an upload without using the user session, and a way to communicate the upload status between different threads. That enables you to set up a session-less page that can get the status of a specific upload and return it.

In the upload page you send the request with the upload, then start sending requests for the session-less page on an interval, and display the status of the upload.

Comment: by using enctype='multipart/form-data' I can progressivly receive the file on server?

Comment: How would you determine the file size on the client?  You'd need the HTML5 APIs for file handling, no?

Comment: @Pointy: You don't determine the file size on the client, you do that on the server side, then communicate that back through the session-less page.

Comment: Ah - the POST header and/or the MIME stuff has the content size.  Ok that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stack overflow question with some helpful links.

[Upload large files in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285120/upload-large-files-in-net)

I believe you can write your own http module to achieve the upload with progress. Here is a link to an example

http://darrenjohnstone.net/2008/07/15/aspnet-file-upload-module-version-2-beta-1/

Hope this helps.

Bob