# Uploading large files in IIS Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis

We have a requirement from a client who wants their clients to be able to upload files of about 1Gb maybe more via the company website.

The website is built using Sitefinity 5.3 hosted on IIS and Windows Server 2008 R2.

I have a couple of concerns with this:

1. I monitored CPU usage during a test upload of a file of 150Mb and it hovered at around 40%, at some point we had it stuck at 99% and the website failing
2. Files over HTTP... aren't we losing all the nice FTP features such as Pause/Continue? I can't imagine their customers being very happy if the upload fails at 90% then having to start from scratch again.

Anyone know why the CPU takes so much heat during uploads? And, is there a better solution to this, besides DropBox and other similar systems.

Thanks,
Jacques

Comment: How are the files being uploaded (Flash, Silverlight, etc.)? What is the traffic like between the browser and the web server, i.e. is there more traffic than necessary that IIS has to handle? You mentioned it, http is a bad fit for this sort of thing.

Comment: One option is Silverlight which is what is used in Sitefinity. That is what we were using during the test.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285120/upload-large-files-in-net and this http://aspnetresources.com/articles/dark_side_of_file_uploads